# Having problems when making a ticket discord JS

Tags: node.js, discord, discord.js

haveing problem when makeing a ticket i dunno what i did everything looks right it would be nice for some help on. i dunno what i did wrong. it looks to me like something went wrong with "message.guild.channels.create" when it trys to create it, it gives me this error the code and the error is below

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "ticket",
    aliases: [],
    permissions: [],
    description: "open a ticket!",
    async execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord) {
        const channel = await message.guild.channels.create(`ticket: ${message.author.tag}`);

        channel.setParent("855596395783127081");

        channel.updateOverwrite(message.guild.id, {
            SEND_MESSAGE: false,
            VIEW_CHANNEL: false,
        });
        channel.updateOverwrite(message.author, {
            SEND_MESSAGE: true,
            VIEW_CHANNEL: true,
        });

        const reactionMessage = await channel.send("Thank you for contacting support!");

        try {
            await reactionMessage.react("");
            await reactionMessage.react("⛔");
        } catch (err) {
            channel.send("Error sending emojis!");
            throw err;
        }

        const collector = reactionMessage.createReactionCollector(
            (reaction, user) => message.guild.members.cache.find((member) => member.id === user.id).hasPermission("ADMINISTRATOR"), { dispose: true }
        );

        collector.on("collect", (reaction, user) => {
            switch (reaction.emoji.name) {
                case "":
                    channel.updateOverwrite(message.author, { SEND_MESSAGES: false });
                    break;
                case "⛔":
                    channel.send("Deleting this channel in 5 seconds!");
                    setTimeout(() => channel.delete(), 5000);
                    break;
            }
        });

        message.channel
            .send(`We will be right with you! ${channel}`)
            .then((msg) => {
                setTimeout(() => msg.delete(), 7000);
                setTimeout(() => message.delete(), 3000);
            })
            .catch((err) => {
                throw err;
            });
    },
};
```

Heres the error

```js
PS C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot> node .
Cbs slave is online!
(node:19344) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined
    at Object.execute (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\commands\ticket.js:7:45)
    at module.exports (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\events\guild\message.js:10:26)
    at Client.emit (events.js:376:20)
    at MessageCreateAction.handle (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\actions\MessageCreate.js:31:14)
    at Object.module.exports [as MESSAGE_CREATE] (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\handlers\MESSAGE_CREATE.js:4:32)
    at WebSocketManager.handlePacket (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketManager.js:384:31)
    at WebSocketShard.onPacket (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:444:22)
    at WebSocketShard.onMessage (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\discord.js\src\client\websocket\WebSocketShard.js:301:10)
    at WebSocket.onMessage (C:\Users\lolzy\OneDrive\Desktop\discordbot\node_modules\ws\lib\event-target.js:132:16)
    at WebSocket.emit (events.js:376:20)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:19344) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of 
an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To terminate the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandled-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejections_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:19344) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that 
are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

Comment: `message.guild` is returning undefined, have you verified `message` is a valid message object?

Answer (score 0):

It says that the guild property is undefined, this might be because someone's using the command in DM's and that's why you're not getting the guild. So what you can do is add an if statement to check if the user is using the command in a server

Here's an example:

```js
module.exports = {
    name: "ticket",
    aliases: [],
    permissions: [],
    description: "open a ticket!",
    async execute(message, args, cmd, client, discord) {
        if (!message.guild) return message.channel.send("You can't use this command in DM's");
      
      // Rest of the code
      
    }
};
```